# Error: 404 when logged in (using hostinger)

Tags: php, authentication, web-hosting

I tried to hosting my php, and found error: 404 when start login. What should I do? I've searched various solutions and repeatedly fixed my php code, but it did not work very well. There is a solution that says that the error is caused .htaccess. How to use htaccess? Please help. I'm a beginner. Here i will include my php code.

**admin-login.php**

```
    <?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM akun WHERE id = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($dbC,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: admin-halomedan.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Halo Medan</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper" style="height: 100%; width:100%; background: #FFBD30;">

      <div class="boxmenu">
        <img src="img/halomedan1.png" style="text-align:center;">
      </div>

      <div class="header" style="padding-top:100px;">
        <form action="" method="POST" style="text-align:center;"> 
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="login_regis"><br/> 
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="login_regis"><br/> 
          <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" class="tombol_login"> 
        </form> 
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

$dbHost = "mysql.hostinger.in";
$dbUser = "user db";
$dbPass = "my password";
$dbName = "my database";
$dbC = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName)
        or die("Error Connecting to MySQL DataBase");
?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($dbC,"SELECT nama from akun where id = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:admin-halomedan.php");
   }
?>
```

**admin-halomedan.php**

```
<?php
   include('session.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Nyekrip Halaman Khusus</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="profile">
      <b id="welcome">Selamat Datang : <i><?php echo $_SESSION; ?></i></b>
      <b id="logout"><a href="admin-login.php">Log Out</a></b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 404 means your file is not found, not that there is something wrong with your PHP (500). We can't tell you how to fix this without more details.

Comment: Which page gives you the 404? The page giving the 404 will either be referenced by the wrong name in your script (possibly due to a typo), or be in the wrong folder... or simply not exist at all. Also, you're not ever actually killing your session, and you really should use parameterised queries to prevent injection.

Comment: @Enstage What details would I explain in order to help me fix it?

Comment: @ObsidianAge How can I get a tutorial about it? Can you tell me links or something?

Comment: PHP.net has [**a great article**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) on parameterised queries, and the 404 error is an absolute *basic* of web development, so you can find tutorials just about anywhere. Remember, Google is your friend, and to always [**do your own research**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking for help. For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)